# how to interchange cookie between javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php

I need to execute a javascript code into which I have to set some cookie info,  redirect to a php page and get such info by php code. I must not use such info as url parameters to transfer to php.

I tried this in javascript:

```js
currentClass = {
  'date': '..some date..',
  'time': '..some time..',
  'instructor': '..some instructor..'
}

var result = JSON.stringify(currentClass);
     
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime()+3600);
document.cookie = "BOOKING_CLASS=" + result + "; expires=" + date.toGMTString() + ";";
window.location.href = '/apps/mindbody/add/bookingmember';
```

location /apps/mindbody/add/bookingmember is routing by .htaccess apache file to a specific php file

The PHP contains:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['BOOKING_CLASS'])) {
   show_error();
}
```

The only data that $_COOKIE has is PHPSESSIONID so such required cookie is not present and error is shown.

I tried setting the path and domain without success!

```
document.cookie = "BOOKING_CLASS=" + result + "; expires=" + date.toGMTString() + "; path=/apps/mindbody/add/bookingmember; domain=mydomain.com";
```

when running, browser stop on breakpoint to show cookies value:

[image]

Following is the browser cookie value:

[image]

No set cookie value exists in PHP.

[image]

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be with expiry time of the cookie. Your cookie gets expired before you try to read in PHP. Try adding an hour to your cookie expiry time. For e.g:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setHours( date.getHours() + 2 );
document.cookie = "BOOKING_CLASS=" + result + "; expires=" + date.toGMTString() + ";";
```

And also I assume that you are in the same domain while reading the cookie.

Comment: it didn't work, $_COOKIE['BOOKING_CLASS'] shows <uninitialized>

Comment: Are you able to share some more info? Do you see the cookie being set in your browser console? It works perfectly fine after modifying the expiry time at my end with an "htaccess" redirect as you mentioned.

Comment: I've found the cause of the problem, the core main platform, is clearing cookies at start site, so is not a php problem.